# Nifi fail to initialize processor when one node in a cluster goes down

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-nifi

I have set up 2 node Nifi cluster with embedded zookeeper. It was working fine. Today in the morning due to some reason Node1 went down(It is not available now). Now on node2 nifi is running and it is showing disconnected from cluster(see the screenshot):
[image]

Now if I execute this flow nifi is generating below error:

> ListSFTP[id=174ee859-f525-316f-8160-5a745a63d3cf] Failed to properly
>   initialize Processor. If still scheduled to run, NiFi will attempt to
>   initialize and run the Processor again after the 'Administrative Yield
>   Duration' has elapsed. Failure is due to java.io.IOException: Failed
>   to obtain value from ZooKeeper for component with ID
>   174ee859-f525-316f-8160-5a745a63d3cf with exception code
>   CONNECTIONLOSS: java.io.IOException: Failed to obtain value from
>   ZooKeeper for component with ID 174ee859-f525-316f-8160-5a745a63d3cf
>   with exception code CONNECTIONLOSS

As far as I understand, if one node goes down in the nifi cluster other node will become the primary node and do the work then why I am receiving this error.
Please Note that this flow was working fine when all the nodes were up in cluster.

Comment: I think the disconnected one is not the one primary. If the cluster is working good and ignore the node that went down, it should be 1/2 not disconnected.

Comment: please suggest how should I debug this issue